# Powershell - OR operator in Select-string

Tags: powershell

In powershell is that a way to put multiple search pattern ? Example below command, I want to search those string that has ASA or TMP. But it doesn't work. The search should match as a single word example: ASA is true but TIASAP is false

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Test\Workflow -Exclude *.bak -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "ASA" -or "TMP" -SimpleMatch | Where-Object LineNumber -le 50 | group path | select name
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you omit the `-SimpleMatch` switch, the [Select-String](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388) cmdlet uses `regex` so you can just search for `ASA|TMP`:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Test\Workflow -Exclude *.bak -Recurse | Select-String -pattern "ASA|TMP" | Where-Object LineNumber -le 50 | group path | select name
```

Comment: how to match as a single word ? example ASA is ture but YIASAO is false

Comment: You can use a word boundary for that `\B`: So you pattern need to look like this: `\bASA\b|\bTMP\b`

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a list of strings you want to match to the -Pattern parameter.

For example, to search all `ps1` files for the words `function` or `check` do:

```
Get-ChildItem *.ps1 | Select-String -Pattern function,check
```

This would make your example:

```
Get-ChildItem E:\Test\Workflow -Exclude *.bak -Recurse | Select-String -pattern ASA,TMP -SimpleMatch
```